# PHP - Closing a MySQLi connection in a try... catch... finally block

Tags: php, mysqli, connection, try-catch-finally

What is the best way of closing a MySQLi connection in a `try... catch... finally` block?

This does seem to work overall, but gives an error when it fails on the first `if` statement (`Warning: mysqli::close(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /path-to-file/ on line 33`)

Here's the code:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if (isset($_POST["login-submit"])) {
        require("db-config.php");

        try {
            $mysqli = @new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass, $dbName);
            if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
                throw new Exception("Cannot connect to the database: ".$mysqli->connect_errno);
            }

            $username = $_POST["login-username"];
            $password = $_POST["login-password"];

            if (!($stmt = @$mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?"))) {
                throw new Exception("Database error: ".$mysqli->errno);
            }

            if (!@$stmt->bind_param("ss", $username)) {
                throw new Exception("Bind error: ".$mysqli->errno);
            }

            if (!@$stmt->execute()) {
                throw new Exception("Execution error: ".$mysqli->error);
            }

        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            $error = $exception->getMessage();
            echo $error; #for debugging

        } finally {
            if ($mysqli != null) $mysqli->close();
            if ($stmt != null) $stmt->close();
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: you need to call stmt->close() first.

Comment: why would you want to close it at all?

Comment: isn't it better, safer and generally a good practice?

Answer (score 0):

Don't close it at all! There's no point to close the connection manually at the end of the script. Once the script is executed the connection will be closed automatically if it was ever opened. Your code has also other problems.

The try-catch has no real purpose in your code. Just remove it. Also, it makes no sense to silence mysqli errors just to throw the exceptions manually. You are adding no value at all, and instead you are just creating messy code.

Your example fixed should look something like this:

```
<?php

session_start();

if (isset($_POST["login-submit"])) {
    require "db-config.php";

    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    $mysqli = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass, $dbName);
    $mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4');

    $username = $_POST["login-username"];
    $password = $_POST["login-password"];

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

By switching automatic error reporting you make sure that if an error happens an exception will be thrown. An exception is like an error and it will stop your script. When script execution stop, PHP will clean up and it will close the connection.